# JavaFX 11 Set Color on a PhongMaterial with fxml

Tags: fxml, javafx-11

I have been endeavouring to implement 3D shapes in JavaFX using fxml, but have encountered difficulty in specifying the static predefined colors in the Color class on a PhongMaterial.

As an example, a code snippet for a Box object is:

```
<Box fx:id="box" width="100" height="200" depth="300">
                  <material>
                      <PhongMaterial >

                      </PhongMaterial>
                  </material>

              </Box>
```

If anybody can please tell me how to specify the required color attribute on this object it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as including a diffuseColor attribute in the PhongMaterial tag,

```
 <PhongMaterial diffuseColor="GREEN" />
```

whereas I had originally attempted to include a nested diffuseColor tag between the PhongMaterial tags.